# Spring OAuth2 authenticate with X.509 certificate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

How to implement X.509 authentication to get JWT token with Spring security.

I tried to implement custom grant_type but can't get X.509 certificate details. Does anyone know how to get certificate details to AuthenticationProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, however this feature is not implemented yet.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4498